# Python 3.2.2 IF behaves differently when run in IDLE vs. run from desktop

Tags: python, if-statement, behavior

Good day!

Today I was writing a small script with Python 3.2.2, and this simple piece of the code 
decided to give me trouble.

```
def main():
    yn = ""
    #...
    while True:
        #...
        yn = input( "---> " )
        if yn.lower() != "y":
            break
```

Now, it should be pretty obvious what this code does however when I run it in IDLE on 
Windows 7 it works perfectly fine, alternatively when I double click on the script's icon 
on my Desktop and open it, it does not matter weather or not I enter "y" it closes, of 
course this is an easy fix by
writing:

```
if yn.lower() == "n":
   #...
```

which is what I did, however I was wondering what the cause of this could be?

Comment: Does the `---> ` get written to stdout when you run it from the desktop?

Comment: Side note: in Python you don't need to declare variables, so `yn = ""`  is useless.

Comment: @Levon: OP says python 3.2, so it would be `input()` not `raw_input()`

Comment: To diagnose, put `print(repr(yn.lower()))` and `input()` before `break`. You will see what was entered.

Comment: @Joel Cornett how would one tell?

Comment: @rubik True, I just thought it was good practice.

Comment: @sdcvvc I tried that, it said "y" (without quotes) 0.0 thank you anway though :-).

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain I think you did not use `repr`, since the output had no quotes. With `repr`, you can see `'\r'`, `'\n` etc. With  `print` alone, you won't see it except a blank line.

Comment: @sdcvvc Thank you! I was actually wondering if you could do that :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me on OSX (Python 3.2.2):

```
yn = ""
while True:
    yn = input( "---> " )
    if yn.lower() != "y":
      break


pu@pumbair:~$ python3.2 test.py 
---> y
---> y
---> Y
---> Y
---> 
pu@pumbair:~$ python3.2 test.py 
---> n
pu@pumbair:~$
```

What executable is associated with the .py extension?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you are using 3.2.2 rather than 3.2.0?

There's a bug in Python 3.2.0 on Windows that reading from stdin sometimes leaves a `\r` on the end of the string and that would explain what you're seeing. Use `yn.strip().lower()` to workaround the bug or update to the current version (3.2.3).

The specific issue is described as http://bugs.python.org/issue11272, but if you are using 3.2.2 it should have been fixed.

Comment: Wow I feel kinda dumb, I thought I had gotton 3.2.2, but apparently not, thanks! :-D